# Как вывести str в одну строку, без переносов строки

Tags: python, flask

Я пытаюсь вывести сгенерированный пароль в одну строку должно получится что-то вроде этого `6yoCm&nN+UZj`, вместо этого получается один символ, я перехожу по порту 5000 и вижу там один символ, при рефреше он изменяется, а нужно чтобы там была сценирированная строка из 12 символов как выше. Я пытался использовать `return(random.choice(symbols), end='')`, но он выводит ошибку синтаксиса. Идеи?

```
from flask import Flask
import random 

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def passwd_generation():
    symbols = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ~$&_+-=/\\"
    for i in range(12):
        passwd = random.choice(symbols)

    return(passwd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.choice(symbols)` - это выбор одного случайного символа из `symbols`. Если выполнить `passwd = random.choice(symbols)` в цикле, то каждый раз предыдущий символ будет перезаписываться. Переносы строк тут ни при чем.

Если вам нужна строка из 12 символов, нужно каждый символ добавлять в `passwd`, а не перезаписывать `passwd`:

```
@app.route('/')
def passwd_generation():
    symbols = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ~$&_+-=/\\"
    passwd = ''  # начальное значение - пустая строка
    for i in range(12):
        passwd += random.choice(symbols)  # добавляем символ к строке

    return passwd
```

По поводу `return(random.choice(symbols), end='')` - эта конструкция не имеет смысла. Вы вероятно позаимствовали `end=''` из конструкции вида `print(random.choice(symbols), end='')`, так вот:

1. `end` - это параметр функции `print`, с `return` он не сработает
2. `return` - это не функция, это оператор, скобки при его использовании не нужны

Вместо цикла с накоплением значения можно использовать генератор:

```
@app.route('/')
def passwd_generation():
    symbols = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ~$&_+-=/\\"
    passwd = ''.join(random.choice(symbols) for _ in range(12))
    return passwd
```

Почитать про такие конструкции можно, например, здесь:
[**Основы Python — кратко. Часть 4. Генераторы списков**](https://habr.com/post/30232/)

Кстати, `@app.route('/')` - это [декоратор](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/dekoratory.html) функции, относится он к ниже идущей функции, а не коду выше, поэтому лучше его писать слитно с функцией (как у меня в примерах), и наоборот добавлять пустые строки выше него (если конечно там нет другого декоратора).

Comment: спасибо большое!)